# Converting pivot code from VBA to PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, pivot, pivot-table

I have Pivot code I need to convert to PowerShell, and I am just not getting it right. Can anyone please help code this conversion into PowerShell?

This is Excel VB Macro Code:

```vb
Sub XX()
  '
  ' XX Macro

  Sheets("PivotSheet").Select
  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Data!R2C2:R1680C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
  CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="PivotSheet!R1C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
  Sheets("PivotSheet").Select
  Cells(1, 1).Select
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("State")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
  End With
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Submit Date")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
  End With
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Actual Completion Date")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
  End With
  With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("State")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
  End With
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Actual Completion Date"), _
    "Count of Actual Completion Date", xlCount
  Range("A8").Select
  Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
    False, True, False, True)
End Sub
```

Here is what I created for PowerShell:

```psh
[void]PivotSheet.Select()
$PivotRange = "Data!R2C2:J$lastrow"+'C10'
$PivotTable = $WorkBook.PivotCaches().Create($xlDatabase,$PivotRange,$xlPivotTableVersion14)
$PivotTable.CreatePivotTable("PivotSheet!R1C1","PivotTable1") | Out-Null
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
[void]PivotSheet.Select()
$WorkSheet2.activate() | Out-Null

$Worksheet2.Cells.Item(1,1).Select()
$WorkBook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = $true
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("State")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlRowField
$PivotFields.Position = 1
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Submit Date")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlRowField
$PivotFields.Position = 2
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Actual Completion Date")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlRowField
$PivotFields.Position = 3
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("State")
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlColumnField
$PivotFields.Position = 1 

$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField($Worksheet2.PivotTables,
  ("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Actual Completion Date"), "Count of Actual Completion Date", $xlCount)

$PivotFields.Range("A8").Select
```

But this does not work yet. I seems to be OK up to the point where I set my first section of the table...

Comment: Define "does not work". Please give an example of expected and actual result.

Comment: Exception calling "PivotTables" with "1" argument(s): "PivotTables method of Worksheet class failed"
At line:1 char:1
+ $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("State")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocat

Comment: Also not sure how to convert this code at the end of the Macro...        <<  Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
    False, True, False, True)
>>--

Comment: Please include error messages with your question.

Comment: I get that error, when i go Line, by LIne when i get to line $pivotfields = $PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("State")
, I get the error listed above...

Comment: This information is vital for your question. Please add it to the actual question instead of burying it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PivotTables("...")` is short for `PivotTables.Item("...")`. PowerShell doesn't allow this abbreviation, so you must use the `Item()` method on a collection. Replace

```
$Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("...")
```

with

```
$Worksheet2.PivotTables.Item("PivotTable1").PivotFields.Item("...")
```

As for translating method calls with named parameters, you need to provide all parameters in the correct order. Use `[Type]::Missing` for parameters that should retain their default value. A trailing list of default values can be omitted, though. In your case the line

```
Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
  False, True, False, True)
```

should probably become something like this:

```
$periods = @($false, $false, $false, $false, $true, $false, $true)
$selection.Group($true, $true, [Type]::Missing, $periods)
```

Comment: When i add the ".Item" I get this error, Ill reload and retry >>Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSMethod] does not contain a method named 'Item'.
At line:3 char:1
+ $PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables.Item("PivotTable1").PivotFields.Item("Sta ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound<<

Answer (score 0):

OK after much development and answers provided by Ansgar. I have the complete code. I have changed the info to "genericize" the code....Thank you everyone for your help. This Code Works and is complete.

```
# Select the cells. 
$Worksheet2.Cells.Item(1,1).Select()
$WorkBook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = $true

#$PivotFields = $Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields($columnFields)
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Field1") # ColumnLables     = "State"
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlColumnField
$PivotFields.Position = 1 
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Field2") # ColumnLables = "Submit Date"
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlRowField
$PivotFields.Position = 1 
$PivotFields = $Worksheet2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Field3") # ColumnLables = Actual Completion Date"
$PivotFields.Orientation = $xlDataField
$PivotFields.Position = 1 
# Set the range of the group. 
$range22 = $excel.Range("a7")
# $range22.Group() # To test the basic group. 
# Here is where the grouping is done. 
$periods = @($false, $false, $false, $false, $true, $false, $true)
$range22.Group($true, $true, [Type]::Missing, $periods)
```